# Buffering one side of line using GeoPandas

Tags: python, line, buffer, geopandas

I have these transects I've buffered as training data, but now we had "edges" defined where we need a simple buffer on ONE side of the line. I run my scripts within Jupyter Notebooks, so it needs to work standalone. Right now my buffer code looks like this:

`lines['geometry'] = lines.buffer(1, cap_style=3)`

`lines.to_file(linesBufferFolder + "\\Lines_Buffer")`

This creates a 1m buffer on both sides with end caps. Like this:

[image: picture]

I essentially need to bisect that polygon, and only keep the "left" side based on the order which the points go. My initial thought was to use a one sided buffer, but I can't find any documentation for that in [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/geometric_manipulations.html) Geometric Manipulation documentations.

My other idea was to simply erase half of the polygon I currently have, but again, to get that overlay I would think I would need to buffer the other side, bringing me back to my original issue. I know how to manually do one side buffers, but finding a Python library that uses it other than ArcPy is stumping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do single side buffer using Geopandas but you need shapely version 1.7 or upper version (due to https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/727#issuecomment-499900749) I do reprojection to a meters based projection in my sample as buffer unit is the projection unit and using degrees is not recommended.

```
import geopandas

lines = geopandas.read_file('https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.geojson')

# Buffer negative or positive depending if left or right buffer compared to line orientation
buffered_lines_positive = lines.to_crs('EPSG:3857').buffer(20000, single_sided=True)
buffered_lines_negative = lines.to_crs('EPSG:3857').buffer(-20000, single_sided=True)
```

Comment: You are a savior my friend! Why is it that Geopandas doesn't have this documented? It took me forever to find the syntax for end cap style as well, you'd think they had it on the docs? Anyway thanks a ton. Saved me a ton of effort trying to bisect these polygons

Comment: Because it needs time. Geopandas uses Shapely and Shapely uses Geos. Each time more abstraction but you need to document multiple times. For instance, not in Shapely although in the source code https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer The same for Geopandas https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html?highlight=buffer#geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/geometric_manipulations.html?highlight=buffer#GeoSeries.buffer https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html?highlight=buffer

Comment: Made a Shapely PR for the doc https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/pull/1110

Comment: PR merged. Now in official Shapely doc

Comment: thank you very much for this. I'll probably need to consult these later, glad I have the correct places to look now.